# How to change CSS of dt and dd elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to hide some elements:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("div.tc-extra-product-options").css("display","none"); 
            $("dt.tm-options-totals").css("display","none");
            $("dd.tm-options-totals").css("display","none");
            $("dt.tm-final-totals").css("display","none");
            $("span.price").css("display","none");              
    });
```

The result is that both div and span are hidden but the dt and dd elements are not. Why is that? and how can I change the css for dt and dd?

Comment: maybe its a problem with class names .. double check your class names of dt and dd .. Everything seems fine .. maybe there is a syntax error ...

Comment: You'll need to provide the relevant HTML for anyone to be able to answer this.